# Matrix with another matrix in each row

Tags: r

I am looking to improve the performance of the code below.  My thought is to attempt to "vectorize" this operation by somehow making each column of st2 its own matrix, is this what a dataframe can do for me?

```
st<-matrix(nrow=257,ncol=10000)
st2<-matrix(nrow=257,ncol=10000)
st[1,]=1489
for(i in 1:10000)
{
  st2[1,]<-st[(256+1),1]
  for(j in 2:(256+1))
  {
    st2[j,]=st2[(j-1),] *exp(.5-(.2^2/2)) * rnorm(10000)
  }
  print(st2[256+1,]) #this for example, in reality I store these values for later
}
```

Comment: Is your equation `... * exp((.5-(.2...)` supposed to be a constant?  If so move that outside of your loops... also I don't see you using `i` anywhere in your calculation.

Comment: I do not see any "i" indices inside that loop, so `replicate` might be faster. For the exp(epression) you could calculate a single rnorm() call and then use `^(1:nrow(st)) to deal with the cumulative product. Should be "vectorizable", so why not make a smaller example, say 5*1000 times smaller, so we have something more reasonable to fool around with?

Comment: `replicate` might be the way to go here.

Comment: I'm less concerned with performance on the inner-loop, as that has shown to be quite fast.  Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: As far as making each column its own matrix, you're probably better off looking at lists or higher-dimensional matrices than data frames.

Comment: And surely you must want an `i` somewhere other than the loop definition? As is, `st2[1,]<-st[(256+1),1]` just sets the first column of `st2` to `NA`, but it does it 10 000 times because it's in the loop.

Comment: @shujaa thanks for the feedback.  I end up storing those values in `st2` and using them later.  The loop just builds up the final value of `st2` and then everything else is garbage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to give credit where credit is due, but @DWin was right on the money...replicate is the solution.